# Const Struct vs Struct With Const Members

Tags: c, struct, constants, c99

Is there a difference between these two?

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int day;
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int year;
}birthday_t;

typedef struct {
    const birthday_t birthday;
    const unsigned int id;
}person_t;

person_t person = {
    .birthday = {1,20,2000},
    .id = 123};
```

And

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int day;
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int year;
}birthday_t;

typedef struct {
    birthday_t birthday;
    unsigned int id;
}person_t;

const person_t person = {
    .birthday = {1,20,2000},
    .id = 123};
```

If a member inside a structure is const but the structure isn't constant (top), is this different than a const structure with not const members(bottom)?

Comment: Would you explain why is this?

Comment: Since you tagged specifically C99 you probably ask about C only, and not about C++?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one language.

Comment: I know the syntax is different for C++ when initializing the members. But is there a fundamental difference between how the const is handled as in the examples? C preferred

Comment: `.birthday = {1,20,2000},` since when did month 20 exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The primary difference is one of intent.

```
typedef struct {
    const birthday_t birthday;
    const unsigned int id;
}person_t;
```

says no `person_t` can ever change its `birthday` or `id`.

```
const person_t person = {
    .birthday = {1,20,2000},
    .id = 123};
```

(assuming the second delcaration of `person_t`) says this specifc person cannot change its `birthday` or `id`, but other person objects might.

Answer (score 0):

Here you made all variables of type `person_t` have their `birthday` and `id` fields be constant:

```
typedef struct {
    const birthday_t birthday;
    const unsigned int id;
} person_t;
```

But here you made it so that only the `person` variable is constant, but any other variable with type `person_t` can be declared as non-constant, and therefore have all its properties modified.

```
const person_t person = {
    .birthday = {1,20,2000},
    .id = 123};
```

Comment: Would you mind reformatting your answer a bit, so that it will attract more upvotes?